# Can we get the exact solution of large-scale quadratic programming problems (quadratic objective, linear inequality constraints) using KKT condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

<sub>[Crossposted](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/42649) at Computational Science SE</sub>

---

Consider a quadratic programming problem with the following format:
$$
\text{min} Q(x) = c^Tx+\frac{1}{2}x^TDx \\
$$
$$
\text{s.t.} Ax\leq b, \\
x\geq 0
$$
where $D$ is a $n\times n$ positive definite matrix and $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix. We know when $n$ and $m$ are small, for example, when both of them are 2, we can solve the problem and get the exact solution using the KKT condition. However, when $n$ and $m$ are large (meaning that we have a large-scale quadratic programming problem. I think we are also able to get the exact solution using the KKT condition.

However, to the best of my knowledge, I cannot find any reference for this. The book '[quadratic programming](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=3b56ceb8bc62ccf82e4d80cbcf58b5c4f307a51e)' said that this type of question can be solved in polynomial time (page 3), for example, the interior point method. But as far as I know, the interior point method only can get the near-optimal solution making the objective function within the acceptable tolerance (like $10^{-7}$).
We can also refer to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92939/can-all-convex-optimization-problems-be-solved-in-polynomial-time-using-interior) about using the interior point method to solve the quadratic programming method.

My question: is it possible for us to get the exact solution to the aforementioned question when $n$ and $m$ are large? How expensive it is if we want to get the exact solution (global optimum) of the quadratic programming problem I mentioned before? And how it relates to the number of $m$? Is it impossible to calculate it even with computers? I will really appreciate it if you can offer some references for this problem.